# tomcat changes 404 status into 403 for http delete

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm having a weird issue where if my servlet sends a 200 ok http status, it works as intended, and the client gets a 200 status as expected. But, if my servlet returns a 404 status, tomcat seems to change it into a 403 status. This doesn't happen if I use the http `get` method. I haven't tested `put` or `post`.

I want to make it very clear that my servlets `doDelete` method gets executed just fine. It's just that the status code returned to the browser gets changed.

I'll provide a minimal testcase demonstrating the issue.

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/api/test403/*")
public class Test403 extends HttpServlet {
    public void doDelete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            String p = request.getParameter("send404");
            if (p != null && "1".equals(p)) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "not found.");
            } else {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, "ok.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

then i test via the following urls

```
myproject/api/test403?send404=1
myproject/api/test403?send404=0
```

What could cause this behavior? I'm not overly familiar the whole servlet/container architecture. I'm only experiencing this issue on 1 server which uses tomcat 7.0.41. I tried another server, which didn't exhibit this behavior.

edit - Per request, here's some output from the network panel in chrome. I used ajax to initiate this particular request:

```
Request Headers

DELETE /xxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: xxx
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: xxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: xxx

Response Headers

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 16 Apr 2014 02:30:32 GMT
```

I didn't remove any headers, although I anonymized some values.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on 7.0.41. What Http client are you using?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I used browser plugins - Advanced Rest Client for chrome, and HttpRequester for firefox.

Comment: Can you post an image of the network console or something showing the request/response headers/body?

Comment: Do you have anything else that you aren't showing us? What does your deployment descriptor contain? Do you have any other servlets involved?

Comment: Or any `Filter` instances?

Comment: my web.xml has an uninteresting welcome file list, and 1 filter which changes the character set( http://pastebin.com/di1JrNA2 ).

Comment: also, the 403 status does indeed show up in the webserver access log.

Comment: I'm stumped. I've made a project with the same config as you and I can't reproduce it. Consider making a Gist and creating a small webapp that reproduces this. I've downloaded 7.0.41 so I can simply pop it in, unless you have a special Tomcat configuration.

Comment: the server that's giving me trouble is a production server that does host a couple other apps. But, I've looked through the config files and very little has been changed from the default tomcat config (config for ssl, ldap authentication - but not on this app). My local tomcat on my dev machine works fine, and I've made all the same config changes as far as I'm aware of...this is just very unexpected behavior. I think maybe later this week I'll look into remote debugging so I can step through the tomcat stack and see what the culprit is. btw - I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck. Let us know what you find.

Comment: I'll be sure to post what it was.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I got it figured out. There was a difference between my local config and the server - the server had a custom 404 error page set up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of...

- an http `DELETE` request
- calling `HttpServletResponse.sendError(status, message)` to send the 404 from your servlets `doDelete()` method
- configuring a custom 404 error handler page(eg, via the `<error-page>` directive in `web.xml`)
- Keeping the default value of `readonly = true` for your context

will cause the client to receive a 403 status instead of the 404 you though you sent.

A request to a servlet can service an http delete request without needing `readonly` to be false, but a request to a file cannot. What happens is that when you call `sendError()`, tomcat will try to find a custom error page that matches up with whatever http status you specified. In this case, it found one (`/my404.html`), and so in order to process it, it basically restarts the entire request routing/dispatching process, including running all the filters on the request. But, this time, since it's a static file request, it comes across a built in filter that looks for http the `DELETE` method, and then checks if `readonly = false`. If it's not, the request is rejected, and it changes the response status to 403 forbidden because you're not allowed to delete the static file named `/my404.html`.

A sensible workaround is to use `HttpServletResponse.setStatus(status)` instead of `HttpServletResponse.sendError(status, message)`, so that tomcat doesn't try to find an error page. As mentioned by @BogdanZurac , you may also need to send a brief response body (i.e., "oops Error 404") in addition to setting the status to prevent it from seeking the custom error page.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on Glassfish with a 404.html error page and JAX-RS Response class. Unfortunately, trying to use  `return Response.status(404).build();`  doesn't work. Any idea why ?

Comment: Oh, apparently you also have to set some content along with the status, otherwise the error page is still returned. So you would have to do `return Response.status(404).entity("Error code 404").build();` instead. Might mention this as well in your answer.